# Prevent element reset to default position in hammerjs.github.io sample page (hammer js ver2.0.1 )

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

As you can see from the [hammerjs.github.io](http://hammerjs.github.io) website, whenever you drag, swipe, pinch or rotate the white square, it will reset back to its default location. I have tried but fail to prevent that behavior, I dont want it to reset back to its position. I choose this example because it's the only example that fits with my map project that run on windows phone 8.

The way I do is canceled out resetElementEnd() inside onSwipe function, I also canceled out

```
mc.on("panstart rotatestart pinchstart", resetElementStart);
mc.on("panend rotateend pinchend pancancel rotatecancel pinchcancel", resetElementEnd);
```

But then whenever I pan it reset back to its default position before it can be panned, and that seems to be the root of many problems. I know that it is something to do with the startX and startY but I dont really get what they are for.

```
var startX = Math.round((el.parentNode.offsetWidth - el.offsetWidth) / 2);
var startY = Math.round((el.parentNode.offsetHeight - el.offsetHeight) / 2);
...

function onPan(ev) {
    transform.translate = {
        x: startX + ev.deltaX,
        y: startY + ev.deltaY
    };
    requestElementUpdate();
}
```

Here is the link include html, css and js files which is basically a simplified version of that hammerjs.github.io sample, the index.js file is the original file and the modifiedIndex.js is that same file but with my cancelling out some of the lines I mentioned above. https://www.mediafire.com/?y7wvady7bhmyrs9

This library is wonderful and I hope I can implement it in my project. Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember the last position of the cursor.

on resetElementEnd() you will save the translate X and Y

```
function resetElementEnd() {

    startX = transform.translate.x;
    startY = transform.translate.y;

    el.className = 'animate';
    requestElementUpdate();
}
```

be sure that you have the transform object fully created:
on line 88 you replace

```
var transform;
```

into

```
var transform = {
    translate: { x: startX, y: startY },
    scale: 1,
    rotate: 0
};
```

hope this helps